# PySide: why the QMainWindow flasked and disappeared when trigger a QAction in another QmainWIndow(Main)

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtgui, qmainwindow

I am a newbie to PySide. I encounter an issue : a new QMainWindow flashed and disappeared when I triggered a QAction from another  QmainWIndow(the Main UI).Here I post the example code to illustrate the above:

```python
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
       super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
       ...
       self.execTaskAct = QtGui.QAction("execute", self,  triggered=self.executeTask)
       ...

    def  executeTask(self):
      task = TaskWindow()

class  TaskWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
       super(TaskWindow, self).__init__(parent)
       ...
      self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Just add `self` before `task` variable. `self.task = TaskWindow()`

Answer (score 2):

You are not keeping a reference to the new QMainWindow after it is created, and since that new window (the `TaskWindow`) has no parent, the window is garbage collected once the `executeTask` method runs.

You just need to keep a reference to the new window, by changing `executeTask` to:

```
def  executeTask(self):
    self.task = TaskWindow()
```

Note that if the action runs twice, this will overwrite the first `TaskWindow` and will make it disappear, or your app crash. You can work out what should happen in that case, or a better method of storing the references of multiple `TaskWindow`s (eg in a list).

Note that you only need to store references of QWidgets if they do not have a parent (which is true in your current case). If a QWidget has a parent, Qt stores a reference internally.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code contains a syntax error by the look of it due to inconsistent indentation which is an issue in python.

More importantly, you have a local object created in the execute method and as soon as your method completes, the locally created object is destructed.

That is because the show() method for qwidgets are not blocking. They will just queue an event for the Qt event loop to process the request when the event loop becomes available.

You could make the variable class-scoped to the MainWindow, but then you could move the creation TaskWindow creation the init method to avoid the unnecessary object creation every time the signal is emitted, and you would only show the TaskWindow in the execute method as follows:

```
def __init__(self, parent = None):
   super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
   ...
   self.execTaskAct = QtGui.QAction("execute", self,  triggered=self.executeTask)
   ...
   self.task = TaskWindow()

def  executeTask(self):
  task.show()
```

If you really wish to construct a new object every time the execution triggered, then you could just prepend the "self" keyword to make each newly created object class scoped. However, please make sure you do not leave not referenced window around in an undefined behavior. So, you would write something like this:

```
def  executeTask(self):
  self.task = TaskWindow()
```

You would need to remove the show() call from the init method of the TaskWindow then for sure.

That being said, I would also assign a parent to the TaskWindow for completeness, either the MainWindow or the application object itself.

```
self.task = TaskWindow(self)
```

Also please note that if you would only like to see one window, you may wish to hide the MainWindow by calling the hide() method of it. If you would like to show both simultaneously, you may wish to consider a TaskDialog as opposed to two MainWindow.

Also, once you finish the execution, you may wish to hide() your TaskWindow explicitly if your user is not supposed to close it explicitly. It depends on your use case.

Comment: Can I ask why you have to move the creation of the `TaskWindow` to the `__init__` method? I don't seem to have any problem making a new window in a method triggered by a signal.

Comment: I'm not particularly interested in a pissing contest. My aim is simply to improve the answers provided, which you have now done by editing your answer to remove/clarify the part I took issue with. However, your answer, as far as I can see, still assumes that there will never be more than two windows open at a time (the MainWindow and the TaskWindow), and instead assumes one extra window will be shown/hidden repeatedly. The poster may want 10 task windows open for all we know from the minimal information provided.

Comment: You said "need to" I paraphrased to "have to". You've changed it now anyway. (the only reason I bothered to reply to this yet again is because I don't want to be misrepresented. If the difference between "have to" and "need to" is a big deal to you, then I apologise.)

Comment: @three_pineapples: I cannot follow anymore what point you are trying to make. To avoid the construction every time (as I wrote), you would need to move it to the constructor. What is wrong about that?